# Mail configuration for Yesod app on Heroku

Tags: email, haskell, heroku, yesod

The instructions [here](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization) use system's built-in sendmail executable, which I can't configure on Heroku (or can I?), so what would be the right approach of configuring mail in Yesod that would work with Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have specific Heroku experience, but I usually use [mime-mail-ses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-mail-ses) to send mail via Amazon.